# Jenkins not able to execute ssh script

Tags: shell, ssh, jenkins, telnet, jenkins-plugins

I have below ssh script which I am trying to execute by Jenkins, it runs fine when I invoke it from shell.

```
#ssh to remote machine
sshpass ssh 10.40.94.36 -l root -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
#Remove old slave.jar 
rm -f slave.jar
#download slave.jar to that machine
wget http://10.40.95.14:8080/jnlpJars/slave.jar
pwd
#make new dir to that machine
mkdir //var//Jenkins
# make slave online
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://10.40.95.14:8080/computer/nodeV/slave-agent.jnlp
```

When I execute this script through shell it downloads the jar file to remote machine and also makes a new directory. But When I invoke it by shell plugin of jenkins, every command runs seprately. so the jar gets downloaded at master and also directory get created at master.

Also I am using sshpass for passwordless automated login, which fails sometime. Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: Try to add `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script. Afterwards, Jenkins shouldn't run your commands one by one anymore.

Comment: Do you know that Jenkins supports launching slave processes via ssh? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Havemasterlaunchslaveagentviassh